# mvc3 extjs 3.4 Turn on delete action after click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, button, extjs, actionlink

I've got problem with delete action after clicking button in MessageBox.
I have something like this:

```
fn: function showResultText(btn) {
                                if (btn == 'ok') {
                                    rec.set('IsActive', false);

                                }

                            }
```

And I need to put here some redirect to open `PartialView`. 
I was trying with return link with  `"../Shop/Delete/' + id + '"`
but its not working. Is there anything in normal MVC view like `actionLink`?

Comment: Just FYI, you've messed your quotes. If that's an actual copy-paste from your code, that can't work. It should be `'../Shop/Delete/' + id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using

```
 window.location = "../Shop/Delete/' + id + '";
```

directly in the button handler.